# How to enable error highlighting in visual c++ express 2008/2010?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, syntax-error

Does visual studio really not come with basic syntax checker? I've got both 2008 and 2010 and they won't show me *any* error, like missing semicolons or unmatched brackets

The closest advice I've found is to enable tools -> options -> text editor -> C/C++ -> Advanced -> Underline Errors in the editor, which doesn't exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out..

"CLR Empty Project" doesn't have this functionality for some reason, "Empty Project" does however.

Comment: Just to be clear for anyone like me coming to this. CLR Empty Project are types of projects when you create a new project not a setting to look for. TY Kzz.

Answer (score 0):

I think C++ projects do not get active syntax checking like the counter parts in .NET languages. The errors will only appear when you build the project.

Answer (score 0):

Tools->Options->Text Editor->c/c++->General-> unchecking "Word wrap" (under settings) could solve the problem. Thanks